# How to enable JBossWS' LogRecorders globally?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8, jbossws

I'm using Wildfly 8.1.0.Final.

I have `RecordingServerHandler` configured, it does get triggered by web services' messages. The problem is, LogRecorders are disabled by default.

The [Records management article](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-Recordsmanagement) says:

> Default processors are not in recording mode upon creation, thus you need to switch them to recording mode through their MBean interfaces (see the Recording flag in the jmx-console).

Enabling them in runtime one by one for each endpoint won't do, I need to enable them globally at "development time".

The same article says:

> The recorders can be configured in the stacks bean configuration

```
<!-- Installed Record Processors-->  
<bean name="WSMemoryBufferRecorder" class="org.jboss.wsf.framework.management.recording.MemoryBufferRecorder">  
    <property name="recording">false</property>  
</bean>  
<bean name="WSLogRecorder" class="org.jboss.wsf.framework.management.recording.LogRecorder">  
    <property name="recording">false</property>  
</bean>
```

What's "stacks bean configuration"? Does the specified `WSLogRecorder` name imply that this configuration creates another, non-default, LogRecorder by that name, and that I would need to add it to all endpoints somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up enabling them via JMX at the end of deployment.

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.management.Attribute;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.ObjectName;

/* ... */

MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
Set<ObjectName> recorderNames = server.queryNames(
        new ObjectName("jboss.ws:recordProcessor=LogRecorder,*"), null);
for (ObjectName recorderName : recorderNames) {
    server.setAttribute(recorderName, new Attribute("Recording", true));
}
```